# Observables from Array typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to create an observable from array, but I am getting error (A tuple type element list cannot be empty) every time. I have tried a lot, but still it's not working.

```
 listdonationsHistory(): Observable<[]> {
     const donationsHistory = [
        {
          id :1,
          type :"Aeri",
          amount: 200,
          frequency: 'monthly',
          date: '17-09-2017',
          account:'ATYTYTYY6778'
        },
        {
          id :2,
          type :"Aeri",
          amount: 200,
          frequency: 'monthly',
          date: '17-09-2017',
          account:'ATYTYTYY6778'
        }
      ];
    return Observable.from(donationsHistory);
 }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Try `Observable.create(donationsHistory)`

Comment: It's not working, still same error.

Comment: @kevin, A tuple type element list cannot be empty

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the function's signature:

```ts
listdonationsHistory(): Observable<[]>
```

Specifically, it's the return type. That is where the empty tuple is.

To declare the return type as an observable that emits an arbitrary array, you could use:

```ts
listdonationsHistory(): Observable<any[]>
```

However, in the implementation you are calling `Observable.from` and the returned observable will emit the array elements separately - in which case the return type should be `Observable<any>`.

If you want an observable that will emit array itself, you should use `Observable.of` instead of `Observable.from`.

Comment: Which is more preferred, `any[]` or `Array<any>`?

Comment: They are the same and different people have differing opinions. I prefer the former, wherever possible.

Comment: @cartant, I have tried it also, but it is also not working. And neither I am getting a specific error in this case. I only get runtime error for this.

Comment: I've updated the answer - it's not clear whether you want the returned observable to emit the array itself, or the array's elements individually. The answer now explains the difference between calling `Observable.from` and  `Observable.of`.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a problem there. The return type is not an array it is an object. If you want the observable to be an array use *Observable.of* instead of *Observable.from*

Try that:

```
    interface Somereturn {
      id: number;
    }

    listdonationsHistory(): Observable<Somereturn> {
        return Observable.from([{id: 2}, {id: 3}]);
    }

    listdonationsHistory(): Observable<Somereturn[]> {
        return Observable.of([{id: 2}, {id: 3}]);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that Observable.of also, but didn't get the solution. Bt Yes there is one thing I am not using Interface.